# Do players that run into each other share Atlas paths?

Tags: no-mans-sky

Ok so my question is pretty straight forward, but let me provide a little background.

I had just got my atlas mission and decided that I would have an actual agenda and start down the Atlas Path.  In my first Atlas Path "waypoint?" for a system I came across planets that had been discovered by another player.

I know what you're thinking and yes it's extremely rare from what I've heard. It also SUCKS MAJORLY.  Now I can't discover things and get the credits, and this leads me to my question.

Are we going to share Atlas paths? Is his path going to be the same as mine therefore the whole time I'm going to go down the Atlas path I'm not going to be able to discover hardly anything?  I'm missing out on A LOT of credits here and since it was only in my 4th system, so far the atlas path I've followed he's there too, I feel like for the rest of the Atlas Path I'm just flat out missing out on a lot.

If anyone has any insight it would be great. I'm also going to keep this updated with things I find out as I play through my game.  Seems kinda like unexplored territory.

Thanks!
RighteousZero

Comment: The Atlas path, from what I can tell, always tries to push you towards the next closest Atlas waypoint. So yes, if you keep following the path that the Atlas gives you, you'll end up on the same trail as the person before you. You can probably fix that by simply travelling several star systems to the side. It might be a bit of an expensive detour, but at least you'll be discovering your own stuff. Alternatively, you can play offline, which prevents the game from downloading other player's discoveries.

Comment: Yeah from what I'm reading I think this is true, we will share atlas paths.  If I play offline won't I miss out on submitting discovery credits?  that's a large part of the credits anyways.

Comment: Playing offline still lets you collect units for discoveries. It even lets you name your discoveries; however, none of that will be uploaded to the servers, so it will be impossible for other players to see that you were the person who discovered something.

Comment: Another option might be to use a black hole? I've not tried it, but I assume it spits you out at some closer point that's not exactly on your original path. It might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

As @Mage XY was saying in the comments above.  There is a chance that you will cross paths with other players, but you will never physically (in game) see them.  That person may have been on the Atlas Path or just randomly exploring and decided to swing by your system and name some things.  If you do not want to "potentially" follow the same path as another, I agree with @Mage XY and @Kat.  Hop into a black hole, or just bump a few systems over and continue exploring.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like where you're at on the Atlas path, you have the option of taking several random jumps perpendicular to the radius of the galaxy.  Every few jumps, you have an encounter that allows you to find the nearest Atlas Station.

Basically, just wander around for a little bit, then get back on the path.

As an additional solution, you are not under any obligation to follow the marked route to the atlas station.  You can take other paths, or skip steps along the route.  It is unlikely that the person you are sharing a path with stopped at every waypoint, every planet along the way.  Simply look for undiscovered systems on your path.  You should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

My experience with following the Atlas path has had me visit a number of star systems already visited and uploaded by several other players.

However, after passing through a couple of systems claimed by other players, I then found undiscovered systems again. Whether this means the players were not following the Atlas path at all, or had different paths to visit, I cannot say.